# Having issues with WireGuard over udp2raw

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireguard

My config is computer to VPS, connection WiFi over WLAN (`192.168.1.x`)

WireGuard config on server :

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PrivateKey = key=+
ListenPort = 51120
#just iptables open ports..
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/up.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/down.sh
[Peer]
PublicKey = key=+
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/24
```

On the client:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
PrivateKey = key=+
[Peer]
PublicKey = key=+
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 127.0.0.1:5666   
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

**Case 1**: just between Wireguard - work :

> (Endpoint = vps-ip:51120  <--> Wireguard work great without udp2raw)

**Case 2**: just between udp2raw - connected:

On server

```
udp2raw -s -0.0.0.0:5111 -r 127.0.0.1:51120 -k "passpass" --raw-mode faketcp -a
```

On client:

```
udp2raw -c -l127.0.0.1:5666  -r vps-ip:5111  -k "passpass" --raw-mode faketcp -a
```

**Case 3**: all together with Endpoint = 127.0.0.1:5666 I lose connection

> Endpoint = 127.0.0.1:5666   <--> wont work

WireGuard over `udp2raw` won’t work, There is no handshake. Why does this happen and why doesn’t it work?

---

last test :
After tested **Udp2raw, Udptunnel, Shadowsock**s remains the same problem.
And after change kernel to 5 , my conclusion problem between (WireGuard- tunnel ) in client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` means everything goes through WireGuard

Except for local connections or anything else with explicit routes in your main routing table. So you need to add an explicit route on your client telling it how to get to the server.

Run `ip route` on the client to list its main routing table:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.11 metric 100
```

Find the default route, and note its gateway and interface (in the above example they're `192.168.1.1` and `eth0`). Then add a new route to your server's IP address (for example, say its `203.0.113.2`) using that same gateway and interface:

```
$ sudo ip route add 203.0.113.2 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

#### 2. MTU defaults are too high for udp2raw

So you need to lower the MTU on your WireGuard interface; `1342` is the biggest MTU that might work. Add the following line to the `[Interface]` section of your WireGuard config (on both server and client):

```
MTU = 1342
```